# Passing a bool parameter from a Kendo view to a controller

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax

I have a read controller that passess in a ViewData["Deposit"] boolean value into a view:

```cs
public ActionResult HONewPay(int id = 0, int bk = 0, int uid = 0, bool deposit = false)
{
    // ....
    ViewData["Deposit"] = deposit;
    //...
    return PartialView(model);

}
```

In the view, i'm making a call to create a payment through Ajax.

I want to pass in the value of this ViewData property to that controller. What data type should be used to pass that value into the controller?

The .Ajax function looks something like this right now...

```js
function postForm() {
// data sanitization...
var deposit = @ViewData["Deposit"].ToBoolean();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("HONewPay_Create")',
        data: form.serialize() + "&cList=" + c + "&pList=" + p + "&kcList=" + kc + "&ksList=" + ks + "&deposit=" + deposit + "&" + getStdURL(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (e) {
        // some logic
        },
    });     
}
```

The controller that would receive it would have the parameter for deposit:

```cs
 public ActionResult HONewPay_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, OwnerLedger item, string otherParams = "", bool deposit = false)
        {
    // do something with deposit value
    if (deposit) {
      // some logic
    }
```

Regarding the `ViewData["Deposit"]` that will be passed around, since params can't really take booleans without parsing, should the data type be a string? an integer?

Comment: your english is not clear can you rewrite your questions?

Comment: @YoussefMohamed Edited. Let me know what part is unclear if it doesn't make sense. Can see this being a loaded question.